# WebClient login and password to the Website

Tags: c#, webclient

I'm trying to log in to https://secure.domaintools.com/log-in/?logout (http://whois.domaintools.com)

```
using (var myWebClient = new WebClient())
{
    string loginData = "username=test@test.com&passowrd=pwd";

    string response = myWebClient.UploadString("https://secure.domaintools.com/log-in/?logout", "POST", loginData);

    myWebClient.Headers["User-Agent"] = "MOZILLA/5.0 (WINDOWS NT 6.1; WOW64) APPLEWEBKIT/537.1 (KHTML, LIKE GECKO) CHROME/21.0.1180.75 SAFARI/537.1";
    myWebClient.DownloadString("http://whois.domaintools.com");
    doc.LoadHtml(page);
}
```

But have this error

> Error 417 Expectation failed

How can I fix that?

Comment: Does this help: http://cjhaas.com/2009/11/02/fixing-the-remote-server-returned-an-error-417-expectation-failed ?

Answer (score 0):

Add this property to your code

```
ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;
```